# threads synchronisation

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have a .cpp file in which apart from main(), two other function are defined- func1 and func2. func2 is the function of a thread called in the following way.

```
  void func1()
  {
       //code here

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, func2, (void*)arg);
  }
```

So, before exiting the function func1 calls func2. Now, what i want that **as soon as func2 exits, func1 should be automatically called**. Note, that to achieve this i can't simply call func1 at the end of func2 because that will mean calling func1 before func2 exits. Also, i can't use a handler which is called before a thread exits(by using pthread_cleanup_push) and then call func1in that handler, because that handler will execute before the thread(i.e. func2) terminates.

Comment: why can't you write func3 that would first call func2 and then your func2_exit_handler and use that func3 as a thread function instead of func2?

Comment: @bobah...There is a problem in your solution...func1 will call func3 thread and then within that func3, the func2_exit_handler will again call func1...so, func1 will be called before func3 is complete and so func1 will again call func3 and this will create an ever increasing number of threads

Comment: for the short period of time you will be having two threads, but that's all. If you just need a "watchdog" funcitonality to make sure func2 is always alive in the dedicated thread then just wrap it into a function with endless _while_ loop and _try-catch_ inside.